# Redundant use of the adverb 'so'?

Tags: meaning

> [maintenance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maintenance) = [mass noun] 2. The `provision of financial support` for a person’s living expenses, **or the support [so](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so) provided**

1. Would someone please confirm the right part of speech and definition of **so**? Is it an adverb and thus the following definition 4 thereunder?

> 4. In the way described or demonstrated; thus

2. Is the bolded cause necessary? It seems just to repeat the first clause? If there's already `provision of financial support`, then necessarily the bolded is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [maintenance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maintenance) = [mass noun] 2. The `provision of financial support` for a person’s living expenses, **or the support [so](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so) provided**

Yes, the word **so** means "provided in this way, in this fashion".

No, the use of the bolded part is not excessive. The first part describes the process of the provision of support:

> *Maintenance* of his children has been part of my duties for the last 2 years.

The second part describes the outcome, the results of the process, that is, the benefits received by the person who is the object of maintenance.

> They received a generous **maintenance** that allowed them to travel abroad once in a while.